# ListView sections with Javascript array model

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to create ListView sections with a property inside a javascript array model, but for some reason, it's not working, the section is not being displayed.

I could use a ListModel but I need to add more properties to the model (enums, functions, etc) and I cannot do that with a ListModel.

My code looks like:

```
ListView {
                model: [
                    {
                        section: "account",
                        title: "My Account",
                    },
                    {
                        section: "general",
                        title: "Interface",
                    },
                    {
                        section: "general",
                        title: "Security",
                    },
                    {
                        section: "other",
                        title: "Help",
                    },
                    {
                        section: "other",
                        title: "About",
                    }
                ]
                   section.property: "section"
                   section.delegate: ColumnLayout {
                        required property string section
                        Label {
                            Layout.leftMargin: 24
                            Layout.bottomMargin: 4
                            text: parent.section
                        }
                    }
                delegate: ....
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the topic of why you can't add more properties etc. to a ListModel? Because it is perfectly doable.

Comment: If I add an enum or maybe a variable referencing other value I get `error: "ListElement: cannot use script for property value"`

Comment: You want to add properties to the ListElement? You were talking about adding stuff to the model (ListModel). Can you give an example. It might be that it can be solved differently. You can always resort to implementing your custom model in C++.